# Thymeleaf editable row in table

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I faced with problem using a thymeleaf template engine.
I have a table with items, and I have task to change tables values in the table without calling another form. I decided to use select-options to change status value but it didnt work.

```
    <tr data-th-each="schedule : ${schedules}">
        <td data-th-text="${schedule.dayOfWeek}"/>
        <td data-th-text="${schedule.hour}"/>
        <td data-th-text="${schedule.minute}"/>
        <td data-th-text="${schedule.status}"/>
        <td>
            <select id="status" th:field="${schedule.status}">
                <option th:each="s : ${statusList}"
                        th:value="${s}"
                        th:text="${s}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: what is the error? Show us the error stack.